# JavaFX RequestFocus

Tags: java, javafx-2

I have an application, where the user can scan a barcode. Therefor I have a textfield, which gets the focus on first load. The application allows further actions for opening dialogs or triggering loading of data. 
I need to set the focus to that field every time the user has finished this actions. 
Is there any possibiltiy to capture all events on the main stage? 
I have tried to add a listener to the focusProperty but this is just triggered on first load and on maximizing the window.

Comment: You need to concrete and specify your question more clearly. You can textfleid.requestFocus on tab closed event. You can capture events on adding a more common event handler on main stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a listener to the `FocusedProperty`. The following code:

```
    btn.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>(){
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov, Boolean t, Boolean t1) {
            //do something
        }
    });
```

works well in my case.